# TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference. at Slide1_fla::MainTimeline/frame1() AS3

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, flash, flash-cs6

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Slide1_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Slide2_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at Side3_fla::MainTimeline/frame1()
```

I have tried all of the sources and still couldn't find any answer to fix this problem.
I am running Adobe Flash CS6 AS3
Whenever I run the script, I get this output and the file doesn't run properly. In the published file, the swf file isn't show completely, meaning the external .swf files are not fitted in the contentContainer.
My code is this:

```
var _swfLoader:Loader;
var _swfRequest:URLRequest;


var _swfPathArr:Array = new Array("Slide1.swf", "Slide2.swf", "Slide3.swf");

var _swfClipsArr:Array = new Array();
var _swfTempClip:MovieClip;
var _loadedSWFs:int;
var contact_btn:SimpleButton;
var news_btn:SimpleButton;
var portfolio_btn:SimpleButton;

startLoading(_swfPathArr);

function startLoading(pathArr:Array):void {
    _swfLoader = new Loader();
    _swfRequest = new URLRequest();

    loadSWF(pathArr[0]);
}


function loadSWF(path:String):void {
    setupListeners(_swfLoader.contentLoaderInfo);

    _swfRequest.url = path;
    _swfLoader.load(_swfRequest);
}

function setupListeners(dispatcher:IEventDispatcher):void {
    dispatcher.addEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfComplete);
    dispatcher.addEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, currentSwfProgress);
}

function currentSwfProgress(event:ProgressEvent):void {
    var _perc:int = (event.bytesLoaded / event.bytesTotal) * 5;
   // swfPreloader.percentTF.text = _perc + "10%";
}


function onSwfComplete(event:Event):void {
    event.target.removeEventListener(Event.COMPLETE, onSwfComplete);
    event.target.removeEventListener(ProgressEvent.PROGRESS, currentSwfProgress);

    _swfTempClip = event.target.content;
    _swfTempClip.customID = _loadedSWFs;
    _swfClipsArr.push(_swfTempClip);

    if(_loadedSWFs <_swfPathArr.length - 1) {
        _loadedSWFs++;
        loadSWF(_swfPathArr[_loadedSWFs]);
    } else {
        _swfLoader.unloadAndStop();
        _swfLoader = null;
        onCompletePreloading();
    }
}

function onCompletePreloading():void {
    contentContainer.addChild(_swfClipsArr[0]);

   news_btn.enabled = true;
   contact_btn.enabled = true;
   portfolio_btn.enabled = true;
    news_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setContent);
    portfolio_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setContent);
    contact_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, setContent);
}

function setContent(event:MouseEvent):void {
    var _swfToAdd:MovieClip;

    switch(event.target.name) {
        case "news_btn":
        _swfToAdd = _swfClipsArr[0];
        break;

        case "portfolio_btn":
        _swfToAdd = _swfClipsArr[1];
        break;

        case "contact_btn":
        _swfToAdd = _swfClipsArr[2];
        break;
    }

    contentContainer.removeChildAt(contentContainer.numChildren-1);
    contentContainer.addChild(_swfToAdd);
    trace(_swfToAdd.customID);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I used to face this problem when the loaded SWF contain "TLF Text".
So the fix? Make "ALL" your textfield in the loaded SWF "Classic Text" and hopefully your problem would be solved.

PS. An easy way to clean all TLF text from a FLA file is to change document script from ActionScript 3.0 to 2.0. Since TLF Text is only support in 3.0, they will immediately change back to Classic Text, and then change your script back to 3.0 again. :)

Comment: I dont know how to change script from 3.0 to 2.0. 
Help Me Please!!);

Comment: Open your FLA file, and open property panel. You should see "script" dropdown which indicate "ActionScript 3.0"